# how to use custom font with auto py to exe and tkextrafont?

Tags: python, tkinter, pyinstaller, auto-py-to-exe

Im trying to build an .exe file with auto py to exe. In PyCharm code I provided works fine and the  font is displayed correctly but when I build exe file and run it, I get this error:

`FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2]: 'C:\\Users\\test\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI21562\\tkextrafont'`

What can I do to fix it, so myapp.exe displays font correctly ?

```py
from tkinter import Tk, Label
from tkextrafont import Font

def resource_path(relative_path):

    base_path = getattr(sys, "_MEIPASS", os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
    return os.path.join(base_path, relative_path)

root = Tk()

font_reg = Font(file=resource_path('./font/Manrope-Regular.ttf'), family='Manrope')

label = Label(text="test",font=('Manrope', 30, 'bold'))
label.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

tried changing paths, with and without the resource_path function, nothing works.

Comment: what command are you using with pyinstaller?

Comment: No command, using Gui "auto py to exe".