# Tkextrafont can't find font file in compiled program

Tags: python, tkinter

In my project i using tkextrafont.
`Font(file="resources/fonts/cs_regular.ttf")`
In IDE my program successfully working, but i starting compiled program i see this problem:
`WinError[2] Сannot find the specified path 'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI137482\\tkextrafont'`

I try using `os.getcwd()`, but this method don't working.

Like this:
[how to use custom font with auto py to exe and tkextrafont?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76620807/how-to-use-custom-font-with-auto-py-to-exe-and-tkextrafont)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jl58q.png

My code:

```
import customtkinter
from tkextrafont import Font

app = customtkinter.CTk()
app.title("my app")
app.geometry("400x150")


Font(file=fetch_resource('font.ttf'))
logo_label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(self.sidebar_frame, text="Text",font=('Font name', 30))
logo_label.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=20, pady=(20, 10))

app.mainloop()
```

```
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2]: 'C:\\Users\\test\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI21562\\tkextrafont'
```

Comment: I have an [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74157641/8512262) that might help. The gist is that pyinstaller (which Auto Py to Exe is using in the background) bundles things into a special temp folder at runtime, so you need to tell your app to look for things in that folder

Comment: Ok, i added your functions and using function like `Font(file=f"{fetch_resource('resources/fonts/cs_regular.ttf')}")`. But this don't work

Comment: Please help. I don't understand where is problem.

Comment: Without seeing a [mre] it's hard to say what the issue is. Please [edit] your question to include a basic example showing what you've attempted so far.

Comment: Maybe error in module?

Comment: 1. `fetch_resource` as I defined it is expecting a path, not just a file name, 2. did you remember to add the font file to your bundle data, 3. that code is not a [mre] - we can't run it as-written, and 4. you shouldn't need `tkextrafont` at all if you're using the method outlined in the linked answer

Comment: I need to using font but that font has path. After compilation my font was not found.
If i dont need `tkextrafont`, then how i can using this font if font not installed?
I using this: `--add-data="resources/fonts/cs_regular.ttf;."`
I need this font for method `Label`

Comment: "then how i can using this font if font not installed" - I just want to clarify: do you have "cs_regular.ttf" available on your machine? It doesn't need to be installed on your computer, but you *do* still need that font file somewhere your project can access.

Comment: Then you just need to use the functions `fetch_resource` and `load_font` as outlined in the linked answer. The last piece is that in Auto Py to EXE you'll need to click on "Additional Files (--add-data)" and add the **full** path to `resources/fonts/cs_regular.ttf`, i.e. `C:\Users\Ben\Projects\Python\MyApp\resources...` (you get the idea)